# Add condition to filter aggregation in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want the count of each values of a variable based on some filter applied in elastic search. For example, I want all the age groups but on the filter that the students are from California.

The age groups is text field and contains an array like this,

```
"age_group": ["5-6-years", "6-7-years"]
```

I kinda want a query like this but this ain't working. It throws an error saying

> unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name [count]: parser not found

```
"student_aggregation": {
    "nested": {
        path": "students"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "available": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "students.place_of_birth": "California" }
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "age_group" : { "count" : { "field" : "students.age_group" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Request help from you troops.

Comment: Can you define "ain't working"? What happens and what do you expect instead?

Comment: @Val I have added the error I get from the query. Can you look into it?

Comment: @Val It says that count aggregation is not working but avg and other functions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there's no metric aggregation called `count` but [`value_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) instead:

```
"student_aggregation": {
    "nested": {
        path": "students"
    },
    "aggs": {
        "available": {
            "filter": {
                "term": { "students.gender": "boys" }
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "age_group" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "students.age_group" } }
                                     ^^^
                                     |||
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

After discussions, the `terms` aggregation was more appropriate than `value_count`. After fixing the mapping (which was `text` instead of `keyword`), the query worked out correctly

Comment: I get the following error for this: "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [students.age_group] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.". Can you tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: Try to use `students.age_group.keyword` instead.

Comment: I didn't understand how do I exactly use the students.age_group.keyword?

Comment: Replace `students.age_group` by `students.age_group.keyword` in your query

Comment: It returns 0 as the count then, like this :       {"available" : {
        "doc_count" : 21024,
        "variant_age_group" : {
          "value" : 0
        }
      }. I have updated the question to show how the age group array is stored

Comment: Your field is called `variant_age_group` not `age_group`, so try `students.variant_age_group.keyword` instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198632/discussion-between-saeesh-tendulkar-and-val).